# unable to import python file module which is inside the another directory of the same level

Tags: python, function, import, module, pylint

I am grinding with an error that is also obvious but confusing related to python.
Attempted relative import beyond top-level packagepylint (relative-beyond-top-level)

The problem is:

there are some folders and some python files and I am getting an error(shown above)

```
-Main
     - one.py
     - two.py
- Root
     - new.py
     - class.py
```

I want to import a new.py which is in the root folder from one.py which is in the Main folder what should I do?
In the new.py

```
def func():
      return 'I am Programmer'
```

and in the one.py

```
from ..Root.new import func
```

I am using this line to import but it gives me an error
Attempted relative import beyond top-level packagepylint (relative-beyond-top-level)

I tried too many lines to import the func which is a function from new.py which is inside the Root folder but what should I do?

Comment: Did you add `__init__.py` files and how are your import statements ? Also, it is not too clear where is your Main folder compared to your Root folder.

Comment: @SpaceBurger The Main and the Root folder are in the same level and also I added __init__.py file to Main and root as well and the import statement is from ..Root.new import func from one.py file to import new.py file which is in the Root folder,

Answer (score 3):

### Explanation

This is a problem I encouter a lot when using Python imports. First, let's take a look at `sys.path` when we run the program. As far as I know, this lists the folders your Python executable will look into when trying to import a module.

**one.py**

```py
import sys

print(sys.path)
```

Now, let's run `one.py` from the root directory of your project (the folder containing `root/` and `main/`). NB: I am using Windows, so the path formatting is a bit different from Unix systems.

**console**

```sh
$ python ./main/one.py

['C:\\Users\\spaceburger\\Downloads\\example\\main', ...]
```

Now we know Python knows the location of the `main/` folder. However, it doesn't know it can go back to the `example/` folder (even if we use `from ..root import new`, don't ask me why...). However you should be able to import other modules from the `main/` folder quite easily. Let's check this out :

**two.py**

```py
print("two")
```

**one.py**

```py
import two
```

**console**

```sh
$ python ./main/one.py

two
```

You can also import from subfolders in of the `main/` folder if you create one. E.g. after creating a file `main/submain/three.py`, you can use `from submain import three` kind of statements.

However, what we want is to import from a folder that is higher in the tree. To do so, I see two options :

### Option 1: change your path

The idea is simple : since Python doesn't know the `root/` folder, we just have to declare it. The idea is simple but this is not something I would recommend to do because it might make your code messy. But sometimes, this is the only way !

For that, you can add the following statements to `one.py` but the preferred method would be to create an `__init__.py` file in the `main/` folder and to add the following :

```py
import sys, os

rel_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "..") # if we use just "..", the path will be based on cwd (which is my download/ folder but might also be anything else)
abs_path = os.path.abspath(rel_path)
sys.path.insert(1, abs_path)
print(sys.path)
```

Now you can re-write **one.py**

```py
from root import new
```

Should work fine (note : `from root` and not `from ..root`). In fact, you can import from every folder in the `example/` folder now.

If you replace `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "..")` by `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "..", "root")`, then you can directly import modules from the `root/` folder as if your `one.py` was just next to your `new.py`. I.e. you should use `import new` in that situation.

### Option 2: change the entry point of your program

The other way to add `example/` or `root/` to the Python path is to launch your program directly from there !

Create an `entry.py` file in the `example/` folder:

**entry.py**

```py
from main import one

one.do_something_with_new()
```

And in `one.py` you can assume the `example/` folder is known to Python and that you can import from evey subfolder there.

**one.py**

```py
from root import new

def do_something_with_new():
  new.do_something()
```

As long as you always start your program with `entry.py`. Be careful with the name of your files, I would usually use `app.py` or `main.py` in stead of `entry.py` but it might cause confusion with your folder names (for python as well). I don't think `new.py` is recommended as well.

### Conclusion

You can either set the entry point of your program in a folder that contains all the subfolders you wish to use and use import statements like `from subfolder.subsubfolder import xxx`, or you can modify your Python path and add the folders you wish to use in to the list of known locations that way you can use import statements such as `import xxx` directly.

However I do not recommend this last option because you might get conflicts with the name of your subfolders (if you have a `main/A.py` and a `root/A.py`, then `import A` will load the first one that is found, which depends on the order of your folders paths in your Python path variable). Also, this takes a few lines of code to write, whereas you can get a result just as nice just with some organization.

### Disclaimer

I usually use one of the two options above because I do not know of any other. This is all based on my experience and reading StackOverflow posts, not on the documentation or anything like that, so please take my advice with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure It will answer your Q but please check this post It may help you:

[Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)